# intl string not working. stil showing error

Tags: flutter-localizations, flutter-intl, flutter-internationalization

i just create a program for using localization.i prepaired documentation. but still issues found. generations file are created but i cant able to call.[image: when i try to build this page happened]

below i mentioned code
[image]

i calling localisation. prepaid documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization

Comment: Sorry this my mistake. i am not added **AppLocalizations.delegate** .